# Discarding a triple because of the absence of monotonicity

Tags: logic

Sorry for the title, but I can not think of a better one.

Starting informally, monotonicity says that if the number of votes for `i` is greater that the number of votes for `j`, the number of seats for `i` must be greater or equal to the number of seats for `j`.

Suppose the vector of votes is `v = {70, 20, 10}` and that we have three vectors of seats in a list, i.e., `z = {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}`.

I observe that:

```
70 > 20 and 1 > 0     70 > 20 and 1 = 1     70 > 20 and 2 > 0
70 > 10 and 1 = 1     70 > 10 and 1 = 1     70 > 10 and 2 > 0
20 > 10 and 0 < 1     20 > 10 and 1 > 0     10 > 10 and 1 = 0
```

which shows that only the first vector must be discarded because it does not respect monotonicity. I have tried the following command  but obviously it does not fit.

```
Table[
  (v[[i]] < v[[j]] && z[[k, i]] <= z[[k, j]]) || 
  (v[[i]] > v[[j]] && z[[k, i]] >= z[[k, j]]), 
  {i, Length[z] - 1}, {j, i + 1, Length[z]}, {k, Length[z]}]
```

which gives

```
{{{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}}, {{False, True, True}}}
```

I need some help, perhaps an explanation on how to fix the bracketing in my poor attempt.

Comment: cyrille, what should be result  if `v = {20, 10, 10}`?

Comment: According to Gambrarelli Minimax apportionments, the rule applies only for inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pick[z, And @@@ MapThread[UnsameQ, {Sign[Differences[z, {0, 1}]],
               ConstantArray[-Sign[Differences[v]], Length[z]]}, 2]]
```

> {{1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

The irregular brackets occurs because you let j run from i which is itself run over. I don't understand why you put {k, Length[z]} last rather than first

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[selectF, orderF]
orderF = Order @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &;
selectF[v_] := Function[{x}, Max@Abs[orderF@v - orderF@x] <= 1];

Pick[z, selectF[v] /@ z]
```

> {{1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

```
Pick[z, selectF[{70, 80, 10}] /@ z]
```

> {{1, 1, 0}}

```
Pick[z, selectF[{10, 20, 30}] /@ z]
```

> {}